SAGE: Correcting Negative Coefficient Visualization in Output
I am using the solve() function to solve a system of linear equations. However, I have encountered an issue with the visualization of negative coefficients on the right-hand side of the equations. Currently, these coefficients are enclosed in parentheses, which makes the display less practical.
from sage.misc.html import HtmlFragment

pretty_print(HtmlFragment('<div style="text-align: center;">Zvoľte počet premenných (n)</div>'))


@interact
def _(n=slider(1, 10, 1, 3)): 
  D = Integer(n)
  example = [[1 if k == j else 0 for k in range(D + 1)] for j in range(D)]
  example[0][-1] = 0
  example[-1][0] = 0
  #example = [[4, 3, -1, 1, 1, 15],[1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 2],[3, -2, 1, -1, -2, 5],[2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

  pretty_print(HtmlFragment(r'<div style="text-align: center;">Zadajte koeficienty rozšírenej matice sústavy \((A|b)\)</div>'))

  @interact
  def inner(A=input_grid(D, D + 1, default=example, label='$(A|b)$ =', to_value=matrix), auto_update=False):
      eqs = []
      pretty_print(HtmlFragment('Sústava lineárnych rovníc (SLR)'))
      for i in range(D):
          eq = sum([A[i][j] * var(chr(97 + j)) for j in range(D)]) == A[i][-1]
          show(eq)            
          eqs.append(eq)   
      solutions = solve(eqs, [var(chr(97 + i)) for i in range(D)])  # Solve
      if solutions:
          pretty_print(HtmlFragment("Riešenie SLR $=$ %s" % (solutions)))
      else:
          pretty_print(HtmlFragment("Sústava nemá riešenie."))


Example
I tried to change show(eq) to pretty_print(HtmlFragment(eq)), but it changes the whole face of the system and does not show the system in TeX.
Can anyone suggest a method to correct this visualization so that the negative coefficients are displayed in a more conventional and practical manner?
